# How to use the mailto: function in php

Tags: php, html

can someone tell me whether the following code is correct, because it give an error when running on the browser. It displays the whole thing on my web page.

```
<li><a href="mailto:<?php echo $ra['email']; ?>?Subject=New%20Mail" target="_top"><?php echo $ra['email']; ?></a></li>
```

Comment: If something renders wrong in the browser, then look at the HTML, not the PHP that generates the HTML. Never describe a problem as "an error", always quote the exact error message.

Comment: What is the output? At first look it's okay..

Comment: can you show error also?

Comment: This is the error,
example@gmail.com?Subject=New%20Mail" target="_top">example@gmail.com

Comment: Just tested and it works fine. The error is something else.

Comment: Yep @MarkM is right. It works fine for me, too. Are you sure, you configured everything else correctly? May you can create a screenshot of the output / error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always helpful to replace any php code with static text to make sure your formatting is working.

```
<li><a href="mailto:email@live.com?Subject=New%20Mail" target="_top">email@live.com</a></li>
```

Your code is correct. Are you sure you have $ra['email'] set to an email?

What is the error it displays?

Are you sure $ra['email'] does not contain quotation marks, which would break `a href="`?

Comment: yes, it does not contain any quotation marks. the email addresses are generated from the database.

Comment: Does the email generated from the database have ANY characters (newline in particular) that you might not be able to see visually, but that could be messing up the code?

Comment: Could you go into the "View Source" of the page with the "error" and copy+paste that here?

Comment: Nice. Glad I could help!